# How can I get a list of content types?

Tags: nodes, 7

Is there any way to get a list of some of many content types?

I am not asking to list nodes of content type(s).

Comment: by hack node template, I obviously mean for child theme.

Comment: Do you want to programmatically get content types shown in `/admin/structure/types`?

Comment: yes, more likely /node/add. however I temporary styled the node template but I would like to render it inside a block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**List of content types**

In code you can have the list of all node content types, using the [node_type_get_names()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_type_get_names/7.x) method :

```
foreach (node_type_get_names() as $name => $type) {
     // Do something
}
```

After, you'll have to sort them if you do not want to use them all.

**Template override**

It is not a good practice *to hack* any files of the Drupal installation.

But you can easily override any template files provided by the core or a module, directly in your theme folder.

Have a look at this subject : [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656).

To have a custom content type template, just take the default "node.tpl.php" file, and copy it in your template theme folder, with a name like "node--[type-machine-name].tpl.php" (you'll have to replace the "_" in the type_name by "-").

**Custom node add form**

And finally I already saw some website using a override node form page using page manager module. But I cannot say how they've done it.